# How to find the string within ${} using XPATH XSLT functions?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I know a few XPath functions suchas tokenize, substring-after, substring-before etc. What is the best way to extract all variable names form a given string using Xpath functions?

For example:

String: The quick brown ${firstVar} jumped from ${secondVar} and then ${thirdVar}

Output: Should give firstVar, secondVar, thirdVar, would use the xsl:for-each to loop over the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handiest way to parse a string for such variables would be to use `<xsl:analyze-string>`, though that is an XSLT function, not an XPath function as you requested. You just need to define a pattern for the variables and then get the results in `<xsl:matching-substring>`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="[[[xpath selector for your string]]]"
       regex="\$\{.+\}">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
         [[[ do your processing of the variable names here ]]]
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
```

You'll find more information on the usage of  in the W3C specification document: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
tokenize($input, '(^.|\}).*?(\$\{|$)')
```

I had to use "^." rather than "^" to get around the rule that the delimiter can't be an empty string, so it won't match a variable at the start of the string. You could get around that by concatenating a space at the start of the string, but there's probably a smarter way.